# Игра "Камень - ножницы - бумага"

Tags: алгоритм, php

Расскажите как реализовать.
Теоретически, код уже сам напишу.
Как написать игру с роботом - знаю сам.
А вот как реализовать 1-to-1 - непонимаю.
Объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

1. Делаете систему авторизации, например, с помощью сессий.
2. Подключаете источник хранения данных, например БД (даже если вам не нужно сохранять результаты игр, сессия, к сожалению, не подойдет).
3. Начало игры инициирует создание новой записи в БД с указанием вовлеченных игроков.
4. После этого оба игрока могут просматривать ход игры на странице с известным им идентификатором игры (незавершенные игры, в которых участвует игрок, могут представляться, например, сразу после авторизации игрока).
5. Для отображения текущего состояния можно производить периодические AJAX-запросы.
6. Нажатие игроком нужной кнопки хода (камень, ножницы или бумага) приводит к обновлению записи игры, таким образом, следующий AJAX-запрос другого игрока покажет обновленное состояние (мол, "второй походил, ждем тебя").
7. После указания обоих ходов, игра завершается, тот самый AJAX-запрос может, например, привести к редиректу на статическую (в том плане, что без AJAXa) страницу с результатом.

Answer (score 0):

Есть два игрока. В самом простом случае будем использовать две переменные. `$player1`, `$player2`. Есть массив в котором хранятся все элементы игры - камень, ножницы, бумага и т.д. - `$elements = ['камень','ножницы','бумага']` или ассоциативный массив, где будете присваивать определенный индекс, как числовой так и не числовой. Потом каждой переменной, т.е. игроку, присваиваем элемент из массива, который выбирается произвольно с помощью `mt_rand` и потом эти переменные сравниваются. Ну и еще нужно учесть приоритет элементов, т.е. камень может разбить ножницы, бумага может обернуть камень, а ножницы могут разрезать бумагу.